# JavaScript to JSON with Keys

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert the parameters from my URL (Example 1) to a JSON Object that looks like Example 2. Unfortunately when I use JSON.stringify() it converts it to Example 3. Can anyone please point me in the right direction for splitting this? I am not sure how to get the keys out.

Example 1 - Input

```
food=apple,banana,peach&store=walmart&customer=John
```

Example 2 - Desired Output

```
{"food": ["apple", "banana", "peach"], "store":"walmart", "customer":"John"}
```

Example 3 - Current Ouput

```
{"food=apple,banana,peach", "store=walmart", "customer=John"}
```

Edits:

Forgot "" in food list

What I tried

```
data = "food=apple,banana,peach&store=walmart&customer=John";
data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: Your desired output is invalid JSON. If that's really exactly the output you want, this is definitely an X/Y problem. You sure you don't want the array items as strings, enclosed in `"`s?

Comment: As @CertainPerformance said, your desired output is not a JSON Object. Please provide an correct output *and* an example of what you tried

Comment: Yes I forgot to put the " " was a bit rushed submitting this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using split, split the string appropriately and insert values in the object

```js
var str = 'food=apple,banana,peach&store=walmart&customer=John';
var arr = str.split('&')
var obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
var x = arr[i].split('=')
  if (i == 0) {
    obj[x[0]] = [];
    x[1].split(',').forEach(function(y) {
      obj[x[0]].push(y)
    })
  } else
    obj[x[0]] = x[1]
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead of manually splitting